# Would adding an index on summed field increase performance?

Tags: database, mongodb, query-optimization

Is having an index on key which we are doing sum with aggregate has any query performance benefits or not.

Comment: How does your query look like. Perhaps if you don't select anything else than the summed field then an index may improve the performance, because MongoDB does not have to ready any data, just the index. However, I don't know whether such feature is implemented in MongoDB. Did you check the execution plan?

Comment: I just made some tests. It looks like MongoDB uses indexes only for filtering, e.g. `$match`. I know other RDBMS (for example Oracle) don't read any data from table if the index contains all required data, but MongoDB does not.

Comment: indexes benefits usually initial filter stages in mongodb aggregation only. Post you whole aggregation so we can check if any optimisations can be made.

Comment: Yes, MongoDB can use a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) when all of the necessary data is available from the index.